# Let $A\in M_n$ and $A\ge0$ and $A^k>0$ for some $k\ge1$. Why has $A$ a positive eigenvector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Defintion:

$A\ge0$  i.e, all $a_{ij}\ge0$

$A>0$  i.e, all $a_{ij}>0$

*Question*

Let $A\in M_n$ and $A\ge0$ and $A^k>0$ for some $k\ge1$.By Perron-Frobeinius theorem, we know that,$A$ will have an eigenvalue $\lambda > 0$.

Why has $A$ a positive eigenvector(i.e, all $x_i>0$)?

Comment: What are the $x_i$ ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde - Let $X=(x_1,x_2,....,x_n)$ be eigenvector of $A$.

Comment: Another piece of the Perron Frobenius theorem is that the eigenvector corresponding to the positive eigenvalue is positive.  Most things that people say about positive matrices can be tied back to the PF theorem.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom - all right, but  in  the Perron Frobenius theorem, If $A>0$ then there is a positive eigenvector ,now here $A\ge0$??

Comment: Note that $A$ and $A^k$ will share eigenvectors corresponding to non-zero eigenvalues. This is true for any matrix $A$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom - Thanks, but, suppose all eigenvalue of $A$ are positive, why does $A>0$?(i.e, All $a_{ij}>0$. by defintion)

Comment: This is not generally true. Certainly, it isn't true for diagonal matrices. Where are you getting that from?